# Div in div positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` inside of a `div` and I want to position the `div` in the centre.

`<div class=\"dialogs-icon\"><img src=\"images/space.png\" width=\"25\" height=\"25\" class=\"d-icon\"><div class=\"messages\">hi</div></div>`

```
<style>
.dialogs-icon {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

.d-icon {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 5px 15px 5px 5px;
}

.messages {
    width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}
</style>
```

How do I make `.messages` centred to `.dialogs-icon`?

[image]

I want to make horizontally center positioning

Comment: You want to center `.messages` in `.dialogs-icon`?

Comment: you should make us a fiddle or codepen with your HTML and css you tried. (use and link fake image at dummyimage.com or lorempixel.com if needed)

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 I have read it, my divs differ

Comment: @user3780736 Can you please show an example of what the expected output is?

Comment: It will be good if you provide fiddle ... you can do this right here http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: okay, made a fiddle for you : http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/8pT3k/ and vertical-aligned your div to image , just in case this is what you meant by center.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 http://i59.tinypic.com/15hhqtf.jpg

Comment: @GCyrillus thank you very much for your fiddle, but i need horizontal positioning

Comment: @user3780736 oki, so in this case with absolute, the absolute element has to be the container within wich content can get margin and width value to react as in the flow: ex: http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/8pT3k/2/

Comment: @GCyrillus I solved this by adding `left: -107px`. And how I can add an arrow like this? http://i57.tinypic.com/33dw12e.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin: auto` in the div you want to center.

```
<style>
.dialogs-icon {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

.d-icon {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 5px 15px 5px 5px;
}

.messages {
    width: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.messages{
    width:250px
    margin:0px auto; //This will center your content but it needs width to be defined
}
```

There is another way to do it by using center tag. Note that center tag is removed from htm5 but it still works in the browsers
hi

Comment: its not working with absolute position but working with relative position property.
And you can see center tag is working too
http://jsfiddle.net/4ntV4/1/

there will be some way to make it work with absolute position you need to play with display property

Answer (score 0):

To horizontally center and have absolute positionning mixed together, you could use the .messages box as a container sprayed ont the whole width of the page, and center its content:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/8pT3k/2/)**

HTML

```
<div class="messages">
        <p>hi</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dialogs-icon {
}
.d-icon {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 5px 15px 5px 5px;
}
.messages {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
   left:0;
}
.messages p {
    width:50%; /* or whatever */
    border:solid;
    background:white;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: I need position `.messages` to `.d-icon`